# when uncheck all the childs parent check box also should be unchecked using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have nested checkbox list items. In my case, if I select parent, all the child's checkboxes checked fine.

If I uncheck parent-child checkboxes unchecking fine and all the child checkboxes check parent checkbox is checking fine.

But my problem is, if I uncheck all the child checkboxes parent checkbox is still checked state only.

I'm new to jQuery and javascript.where to change my code.Any help would be appreciated.Thanks in Advance.

```js
$(function() {
  $('li :checkbox').on('click', function() {
    var $chk = $(this),
      $li = $chk.closest('li'),
      $ul, $parent;
    if ($li.has('ul')) {
      $li.find(':checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked)
    }
    do {
      $ul = $li.parent();
      $parent = $ul.siblings(':checkbox');
      if ($chk.is(':checked')) {
        $parent.prop('checked', $ul.has(':checkbox:not(:checked)').length == 0)
      } else {
        $parent.prop('checked', true)
      }
      $chk = $parent;
      $li = $chk.closest('li');
    } while ($ul.is(':not(.someclass)'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
  <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='5'>A1
    <ul>
      <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='26'>a2
        <ul>
          <li class='chkbox' ;>
            <input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='29'>a3
            <li class='chkbox' ;>
              <input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='30'>a4
        </ul>
        <li class='chkbox'>
          <input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='25'>a1
          <ul>
            <li class='chkbox' ;><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='27'>aaaaaa
              <li class='chkbox' ;><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='28'>abbbbbb
          </ul>
    </ul>
    <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='6'>A2
      <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='7'>A3
        <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='8'>A4
          <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='9'>A5
            <div style="clear:both">
            </div>
</div>
<div id="2" class="tab-pane fade">
  <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='10'> B1
    <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='11'>B2
      <div style="clear:both">
      </div>
</div>
<div id="3" class="tab-pane fade">
  <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='12'>C1
    <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='13'>C2
      <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='14'>C3
        <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='17'>A6
          <ul>
            <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='19'>A8
              <ul>
                <li class='chkbox' ;><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='21'>A10
                  <ul>
                    <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='23'>A13
                      <ul>
                        <li class='chkbox' ;><input type='checkbox' name='names[]' value='31'>jjj
                          <li class='chkbox' ;><input type='checkbox' name='names[]' value='32'>kkk
                      </ul>
                      <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='24'>A14
                        <ul>
                        </ul>
                  </ul>
                  <li class='chkbox' ;><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='22'>A11
              </ul>
              <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='20'>A9
          </ul>
          <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='18'>A7
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
<div id="4" class="tab-pane fade">
  <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='15'>D1
    <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='16'>D2
      <div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just forgot one corner case below one

`if($ul.get(0))
    if($ul.find(':checkbox:checked').length !== 0)
        $parent.prop('checked', true)`

```js
$(function() {
  $('li :checkbox').on('click', function() {
    var $chk = $(this),
      $li = $chk.closest('li'),
      $ul, $parent;
    if ($li.has('ul')) {
      $li.find(':checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked)
    }
    do {
      $ul = $li.parent();
      $parent = $ul.siblings(':checkbox');
      if ($chk.is(':checked')) {
        $parent.prop('checked', $ul.has(':checkbox:not(:checked)').length == 0)
      } else {
        $parent.prop('checked', false)
      }
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^//
      if($ul.get(0))
   if($ul.find(':checkbox:checked').length !== 0)
          $parent.prop('checked', true)          
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^//
      $chk = $parent;
      $li = $chk.closest('li');
     
    } while ($ul.is(':not(.someclass)'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
  <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='5'>A1
    <ul>
      <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='26'>a2
        <ul>
          <li class='chkbox' ;>
            <input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='29'>a3
            <li class='chkbox' ;>
              <input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='30'>a4
        </ul>
        <li class='chkbox'>
          <input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='25'>a1
          <ul>
            <li class='chkbox' ;><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='27'>aaaaaa
              <li class='chkbox' ;><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='28'>abbbbbb
          </ul>
    </ul>
    <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='6'>A2
      <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='7'>A3
        <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='8'>A4
          <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='9'>A5
            <div style="clear:both">
            </div>
</div>
<div id="2" class="tab-pane fade">
  <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='10'> B1
    <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='11'>B2
      <div style="clear:both">
      </div>
</div>
<div id="3" class="tab-pane fade">
  <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='12'>C1
    <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='13'>C2
      <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='14'>C3
        <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='17'>A6
          <ul>
            <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='19'>A8
              <ul>
                <li class='chkbox' ;><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='21'>A10
                  <ul>
                    <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='23'>A13
                      <ul>
                        <li class='chkbox' ;><input type='checkbox' name='names[]' value='31'>jjj
                          <li class='chkbox' ;><input type='checkbox' name='names[]' value='32'>kkk
                      </ul>
                      <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='24'>A14
                        <ul>
                        </ul>
                  </ul>
                  <li class='chkbox' ;><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='22'>A11
              </ul>
              <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='20'>A9
          </ul>
          <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='18'>A7
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
<div id="4" class="tab-pane fade">
  <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='15'>D1
    <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='16'>D2
      <div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Comment: I think toggling `a3` should not toggle `A1`

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Thanks for the help. But if I select a2 parent of A1 also should be checked

Comment: You need to remove the else statements  `$parent.prop('checked', true)` I had modified my answer.

Comment: If you select a2 parent of A1 also should be, can't this statement contradictory? because if A1 is selected which means all childs are selected.

Comment: if i select A1 all the child elements of a1 and a2 are checking fine.if select only the a2 or a1 also A1 should selected state only

Comment: Okay then you should have to enable else condition with make parent checked false `$parent.prop('checked', false)`, I had also update the answer.

Comment: if i select either of a1 or a2 and both a1 and a2 also A1 should be selected state only.please check.thanks in advance.

Comment: I had updated my answer please check and let me know, if this is what your expected result?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160407/discussion-between-itsme-and-shailesh-rathod).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you need to run on 2 directions - up and down (in the hierarchy tree).

For up, you can use [`parents`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) and do the check for each parent.

For down, you just need to find the sibling `ul` and find within it all the `:checkbox`s.

Also, I changed the event from `click` to `change` - the event which meant to handle changes in the state of the checkbox.

Let me know if something is not clear.

```js
$(':checkbox').on('change', function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      checked = $this.is(':checked');
      
  toggleParents($this, checked);
  //toggleChildren($this, checked);
});

function toggleParents(checkbox, checked) {
  checkbox.parents('li').each(function() {
    var $parent = $(this);
    $parent.children(':checkbox').prop('checked', checked);
  });
}

function toggleChildren(checkbox, checked) {
  checkbox.siblings('ul').find(':checkbox').each(function() {
    $(this).prop('checked', checked);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
  <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='5'>A1
    <ul>
      <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='26'>a2
        <ul>
          <li class='chkbox' ;>
            <input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='29'>a3
            <li class='chkbox' ;>
              <input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='30'>a4
        </ul>
        <li class='chkbox'>
          <input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='25'>a1
          <ul>
            <li class='chkbox' ;><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='27'>aaaaaa
              <li class='chkbox' ;><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='28'>abbbbbb
          </ul>
    </ul>
    <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='6'>A2
      <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='7'>A3
        <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='8'>A4
          <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='9'>A5
            <div style="clear:both">
            </div>
</div>
<div id="2" class="tab-pane fade">
  <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='10'> B1
    <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='11'>B2
      <div style="clear:both">
      </div>
</div>
<div id="3" class="tab-pane fade">
  <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='12'>C1
    <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='13'>C2
      <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='14'>C3
        <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='17'>A6
          <ul>
            <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='19'>A8
              <ul>
                <li class='chkbox' ;><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='21'>A10
                  <ul>
                    <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='23'>A13
                      <ul>
                        <li class='chkbox' ;><input type='checkbox' name='names[]' value='31'>jjj
                          <li class='chkbox' ;><input type='checkbox' name='names[]' value='32'>kkk
                      </ul>
                      <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='24'>A14
                        <ul>
                        </ul>
                  </ul>
                  <li class='chkbox' ;><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='22'>A11
              </ul>
              <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='20'>A9
          </ul>
          <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='18'>A7
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
<div id="4" class="tab-pane fade">
  <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='15'>D1
    <li class='chkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='myCheckbox' name='names[]' value='16'>D2
      <div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Comment: sorry for the late response.i what i want is if select a2 A1 should checked state only.

Comment: I just was updating my answer (don't run `toggleChildren`). Let me know if that is what you expecting..

Comment: if i select A1 all the child elements of a1 and a2 are checking fine.if select only the a2 or a1 also A1 should selected state only.and the childs if a1 should be checked if i select a1 and same way for a2 also.